# Redux Thunk, Modifying state: Unhandled promise rejection: Error: [Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property]

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, redux-thunk, immer.js

While working on a React Native application with a persistent Redux store (in TypeScript) I ran into the following problem:

I built a Thunk that queries an API, this API sends back a set of question data in a fetch. This fetch works fine, but when trying to save any data to the Redux Store using `extraReducers` I get errors.

My code looks like this:

First I call a dispatch on the Thunk in my page:

```
questionpage.tsx

-stuff-

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('dispatching fetch')
        dispatch(fetchQuestions())

    }, []);

-render stuff-
```

The actual thunk looks like this and does a fetch to my API:

```
export const fetchQuestions = createAsyncThunk('questions/fetchquestions', async () =>{
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + Base64.btoa(email + ":" + password))
    
    const response = await fetch(api + "/api/questions", {
            headers: headers,
            method: 'GET'
        })
    const stuff = await response.json();
    console.log(stuff)
    return stuff;

})
```

Then:

```
questionSlice

    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchQuestions.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'loading' // < when I comment this the console.log works
          console.log('pending')
        }),
        builder.addCase(fetchQuestions.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'succeeded'
          // Add any fetched posts to the array
          state.questions = state.questions.concat(action.payload) // < comment this, console.log works
          console.log('fulfilled')
        })
        builder.addCase(fetchQuestions.rejected, (state, action) => {
          state.status = 'failed' // < when I comment this the console.log works
          state.error = action.error.message // < when I comment this the console.log works
          console.log('rejected')
        })
      }
```

As you see above: In my reducer I use the `extraReducers` to catch the different results this Thunk can produce. This works, but only when I modify nothing in the state. If I try to save anything to the state I get the following error:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: [Immer] Immer only supports setting array indices and the 'length' property]
```

This error occurs at all times, it occurs when I modify `state.status`, which is a String, not an Array, it also occurs when I modify `state.error` and `state.questions`
The last one is an array, but the other two are not.

I looked at a lot of other questions but couldn't find this specific scenario anywhere and am fairly lost on how to proceed.

Update:
My problem stems from `Immer`. If I understand the documentation correctly `Immer` should allow me to do updates of objects in the Redux state, but I cannot get it to work:

```
export const questionSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'question',
    initialState,
    reducers: { 
        save: (state, action) => {
            state.questions.push(action.payload) < this action works
        }
    },
    extraReducers: (builder) => {
        builder.addCase(fetchQuestions.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
          state.questions.push(action.payload) < this action errors
        })
```

Edit 2:

Pointed towards this direction and posting my state here. The app only has one current Slice, the QuestionSlice from earlier, with this state:

```js
interface questionState {
    questions: object[],
    status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed',
    error: string | undefined
}

const initialState: questionState = {
    questions : [],
    status: 'idle',
    error: undefined
}
```

This goes into the `RootReducer`

`const rootReducer = combineReducers({questions: questionReducer})`

And then this `RootReducer` is used to build the store:

````js
const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage: AsyncStorage
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);


const mystore = createStore(
    persistedReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
);```

The comment Phry made pointed towards my state being an array of itself, but that doesn't seem to be the case to me. There's also no code I can find that modifies the state to be an array. I'll try and see if I can make a basic version of the project later that others could look at, but it might be a lot of work with my level of experience.
````

Comment: This is very odd. Immer _should_ allow "mutating" the state, and I'm very confused why your examples are throwing errors. Can you create and link a project that demonstrates this problem happening?

Comment: @markerikson Creating a project would be a bit out of my reach currently as this code is part of a thesis project that I cannot share in it's entirety. Phry shared an insight on the other answer that probably explains my problem though.

Comment: Arrays _can_ be modified with Immer, just fine, which is part of why I'm confused. If you can't share the entire project, a smaller version that shows the same issue would be helpful. Basically, we know that Immer works fine, and your code _should_ be okay in general, so there's got to be something specific to _your_ app that's going on here.

Comment: @markerikson I posted my Slice with the state I built, it looks fine to me, I can't find anywhere where I am modifying it into an array. I'll try to make a version of the project that I can share here, although it might take too much time with my level of experience.

Answer (score 2):

My fix was as follows:

Even though I got an `Immer` error and I should be able to do state modification inside the Reducer, if I understand the documentation correctly: [this](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#simplifying-immutable-updates-with-redux-toolkit) specific part of the documentation, it just didn't work.

I take it there is something with the `extraReducers` that gives me that `Immer` error. I got my code to work by changing it to be immutable updates.

```
builder.addCase(fetchQuestions.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
            // Add any fetched posts to the array
            console.log('fulfilled')
            
            return state = {
                ...state,
                status: 'succeeded',
                questions: action.payload
            }
        })
```

Comment: You should re-check your code nonetheless - at some point you are probably accidentally changing your state shape to an array. Does any of your other reducers maybe have a `return []` or is your `initialState` `[]` ?

Comment: @phry
My initial `questions` is indeed an array. Is there a more recommended way to store a set of data? I was under the impression that arrays were totally fine and I saw many examples online with them. If it's actually just the fact that arrays can't be modified with `Immer` then the original error makes sense, but without an alternative method of storing a set of data I'd still be left with this code.

Comment: `{ questions: [] }` is totally okay. But from the error message it seems that your state itself is an array, not the `questions` property.

Comment: @phry I posted my Slice with the state I built, it looks fine to me, I can't find anywhere where I am modifying it into an array. I'll try to make a version of the project that I can share here, although it might take too much time with my level of experience.

Comment: Try to reproduce it on https://codesandbox.io/, that might be easiest for you top reproduce

Answer (score 0):

in the reducers you have to copy your state as it is immutable you can't just change a property on it.

[read more here](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns)

Comment: I have read this, yes. But this project uses the `createSlice` to allow you to do mutable updates on variables, using the `Immer` library. I have read about this and I was under the impression that it allowed me to change properties inside there? I take it that is incorrect then. Do you know how to replace the state with my queried data in that case?

```
export const questionSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'question',
    initialState,
    reducers: { 
        save: (state, action) => {
            state.questions.push(action.payload) < this works.
        }

Comment: I'm having some trouble sending a comment, sorry, new to this website. I will edit my post instead.

Comment: i don't know about that library but i know there are libraries that handle immutability for you if you wouldn't use those the change would look something like this => `{...state, questions: [...questions, action.payload]}`

Comment: I got it to work, posted my answer. Thank you for your help.